# errors after migration from Selenium 2.47.0 to Selenium 3.13.0 with FF 54

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

so I finally decided to migrate my framework from 2.47.0 to 3.13.0. Here are the things I changed:
1. Removed selenium 2.47.0 jar files and added 3.13.0 jar files to build path
2. Downloaded Gecko driver 0.21.0
3. Updated FF to 54 (tried latest 62 too)
4. Updated selenium dependency to 3.13.0 in pom.xml
5. My java version is 1.8.0_171

I am testing this migration with test project.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUpDriver() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      //FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
      //options.setCapability("marionette", false);
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\****\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }    

    @Test(priority=1) 
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
```

I am getting following exception when I run this:
Running TestSuite

```
1532713601535   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
1532713601547   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:3012
1532713602248   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.LUNdmVpn3N1s"
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64.dll v=0.0.0.0
1532713605654   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 50526
Jul 27, 2018 1:47:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 76.062 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setUpDriver(********.Test1)  Time elapsed: 75.988 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
WebDriver:NewSession
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: '******-LAPTOP', ip: '*******', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:211:5
UnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:455:5
execute/req<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:503:15
TaskImpl_run@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:319:42
TaskImpl@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:277:3
asyncFunction@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:252:14
Task_spawn@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:166:12
execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:500:15
onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:471:7
_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js -> resource://devtools/shared/transport/transport.js:483:11
exports.makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:101:14
exports.makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:101:14
```

NOTE: I tried setting marionette to false with FF 47.0 and Selenium 3.13.0 and it worked fine but I want to use latest FF version so I want to make sure its working with Geckodriver. 
Any help would be greatlyappreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted it out by downgrading my gecko driver to v0.16.1

Comment: its really weird, now I upgraded back to v0.21.0 and everything is working as it should be